# How do the connections to the time travelers work?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

I have only a vague idea (maybe intended by the writers) of how the (real time) connections between the splinter machine and the time travelers work and what their limitations are.

Early they use the term "connection" later "real time connection", I'm not sure if this is the same or two different types of connections.

My understanding is, that if someone splinters into the past, there is a (real time?) connection between him and the splinter machine, which is a kind of lock that enables the splinter machine to bring him back to the "present" (from the pov of the splinter machine, for us of course the future). If the machine gets the traveler back lets say 2h after it send it to the past, the traveler experiences 2h into the past. That means time proceeds for the traveler and the people of the future at the same speed.

Sometimes the connection is broken and they cannot bring the traveler back. Sometimes it is broken deliberately.
The traveler makes a newspaper ad to inform the future people where and when to pick him up.
In this case it is possible that the traveler was one year in the past while in the future they just wait a few minutes.
So it seems to be enough for the splinter machine to know a location and a time to lock on the traveler again. Sometimes an injection is needed which seems to also act as a locking mechanism.

In one case Katarina needs to wait one year for the "real time connection" to catch up before she could get two time travelers back.

So how exactly do the connections work? What breaks them? What is needed to reastablish them? Why they sometimes need an injection and sometimes just an ad to be established?

Why sometimes they have to wait to "catch up" instead of getting the traveler back immediately after he departs (but from his pov letting him a longer time in the past)?

So generally asked, what are the mechanics of the connection?